# Api::V1::CompaniesController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'm getting this error and I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this.
Initially it was going to be just a rest api, but now I've decided to add a front-end as well, so I added the 'slim-rails' gem and tried to create the front-end for my companies_controller but I'm stuck with this error, it works fine if I request a JSON, but for some reason it doesn't find the template and I get "Api::V1::CompaniesController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html". Most of the research I've done points to wrong names, but apparently everything is fine. Here is my code:

**companies_controller.rb**

```
module Api
    module V1
        class CompaniesController < ApplicationController            
            before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
            #List all
            def index
                # TODO validate and filter based on user role permissions
                @companies = Company.order('active DESC, name')
                respond_to do |format|
                    format.html 
                    format.json { json_response(@companies , status: :ok) }
                end
            end

            #other controller methods

            private

            def set_company
                @company = Company.find(params[:id])
            end

            def company_params
                params.require(:company).permit(:id, :name, :active, :city_id)
            end

        end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :states, only: :index
      resources :companies
    end
  end
end
```

**index.html.slim**

```
h1 Listing companies

table
  thead
    tr
      th Name
      th Active
      th City
      th
      th
      th

  tbody
    - @companies.each do |company|
      tr
        td = company.name
        td = company.active
        td = company.city
        td = link_to 'Show', company
        td = link_to 'Edit', edit_company_path(company)
        td = link_to 'Destroy', company, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete

br

= link_to 'New Company', new_company_path
```

**Project Structure**

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Adding a front-end to an API application is just all kinds of backwards. If you already have an API then a better alternative is to use a SPA framework like React, Vue, Ember, Angular etc to build a frontend that consumes your API.

Comment: Adding an API to an existing "classical" application has been commonly done but what you are doing is like attaching a horse to pull your car.

Comment: The error message will have sequence of file places and sequence of file formats  Rails is looking for. Check it and post it in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Because the Controller is in the `Api::V1` namespace, Rails will be looking for views in the same namespace, which means it'll be looking for a view in `app/views/api/v1/companies/index.html.slim`. And that directory of course doesn't exist. You could try creating that directory and moving the file there.

However, I don't think that's a good idea. API Controllers should be separate from view-based Controllers. If you want to keep everything in the same application (both the API and the frontend), I'd suggest creating a new Controller for handling the frontend in the root namespace, e.g. `app/controllers/companies_controller.rb`. Then that Controller will just act like a "normal" Rails Controller, rather than an API-specific one.

Or you could do like @max suggested and just have an entirely separate application for the frontend. That would be ideal, but if you're just working on a demo/side project, it might be overkill for now.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I also had to adjust the routes and remove the modules Api and V1 from the controllers. Thank you very much.